# Absolute Galois group of a tensor product of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Suppose $k, K, L$ are fields of null carachteristic such that $K$ and $L$ are finite Galois extensions of $k$ with $K\otimes_{k}L$ a field with the separable closure of $k$ being finite dimensional over $k$.

Let $\mathcal{G}_{K_{i}}$ the absolute Galois group of $K_{i}$.

What is the structure of $\mathcal{G}_{K\otimes_{k}L}$? Is it isomorphic to the group generated by $\operatorname{Gal}(K/k)\cap\operatorname{Gal}(L/k)$ or are additional hypotheses required?

Comment: what is $K_i$ here ? Is it an arbitrary field containing $K$ ?

Comment: You say the separable closure of $k$ is finite-dimensional over $k$. That is severely restrictive: by the Artin-Schreier theorem it means $k$ is algebraically closed or its algebraic closure is the quadratic extension $k(\sqrt{-1})$, so $K$ and $L$ each have just 1 or 2 choices. Everything is quite limited, so there is very little generality in the question. What were you really trying to do here?

Comment: Also perhaps the OP wants to know that if $K\otimes_{k}L$ is a field (thus $=KL$) then $Aut(KL/k) \cong Aut(K/k)\times Aut(L/k)$, when $K/k,L/k$ are Galois this is a iff.

Comment: Yes, indeed I'm interested in this.

Comment: @Why: yes, an arbitrary field containing $k$. I use a different notation to avoid any ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you remind us what is the absolute Galois group? And $K\otimes_k L$ is a field means that it is isomorphic to $KL$ for any $k$-embedding of $K,L$ into $\overline{k}$.

Next
$$Aut(F/KL) = Aut(F/K)\cap Aut(F/L)$$ without any assumption other than $K,L$ are subfields of $F$.

Comment: $\mathcal{G}_{K}=\operatorname{Gal}(\bar{K}/K)$.

Comment: So, do you need more clues?

Comment: Maybe. Taking $K$ and $L$ in $\{R,C\}$, can we consider $\mathcal{G}_{C\otimes_R C}$?